# Flink use of .keyBy with KeySelector taking data from Kafka

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have Flink script in java with Kafka connector. I'm getting the data from Kafka with no issues, first step I'm doing a .map to get the time stamp from the messages. To use event time windows i extracted the time stamp in milliseconds from the data and return it to flink. To do this i used "assignTimestampsAndWatermarks"

```
 DataStream<String> kafkaData = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer("CorID_0", new SimpleStringSchema(), p));

    kafkaData.map(new MapFunction<
            String, Tuple19<String, String, String, String, String,
            String, Double, Long, Double, Long,
            Long, Integer, Long, Double, Long,
            Double, Double, Integer, Double>>()
    {
        public Tuple19<String, String, String, String, String,
                String, Double, Long, Double, Long,
                Long, Integer, Long, Double, Long,
                Double, Double, Integer, Double> map(String value)
        {
            String[] words = value.split(",");
            return new Tuple19<String, String, String, String, String,
                    String, Double, Long, Double, Long,
                    Long, Integer, Long, Double, Long,
                    Double, Double, Integer, Double>
                    (words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5], Double.parseDouble(words[6]),
                            Long.parseLong(words[7]), Double.parseDouble(words[8]), Long.parseLong(words[9]),
                            Long.parseLong(words[10]), Integer.parseInt(words[11]),
                            Long.parseLong(words[12]), Double.parseDouble(words[13]),
                            Long.parseLong(words[14]), Double.parseDouble(words[15]),
                            Double.parseDouble(words[16]), Integer.parseInt(words[17]),
                            Double.parseDouble(words[18]));
        }
    })

            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Tuple19<String, String, String, String, String,
                    String, Double, Long, Double, Long,
                    Long, Integer, Long, Double, Long,
                    Double, Double, Integer, Double>>()
            {
                private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                
                public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Tuple19<String, String, String, String, String,
                        String, Double, Long, Double, Long,
                        Long, Integer, Long, Double, Long,
                        Double, Double, Integer, Double> value)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(sdf.parse(value.f3).getTime());
                        return ts.getTime();
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Parsing Error");
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Second step is where the calculation start. I'm trying to do some manipulation of the data and to do this I need to get the data from the kafka message, this is where i got stuck basically.**

```
DataStream<String> largeDelta = kafkaData .keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple19<String,String,String,String,String,
                String,Double,Long,Double,Long,
                Long,Integer,Long,Double,Long,
                Double,Double, Integer,Double>, String>()
                {
            public String getKey(Tuple19<String,String,String,String,String,
                    String,Double,Long,Double,Long,
                    Long,Integer,Long,Double,Long,
                    Double,Double, Integer,Double> value)
                {
                return value.f2;
                }
                })

                 .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5)))
                 .process(new TrackChanges(5));
        largeDelta.writeAsText("/Alert.txt");
        env.execute("ABCD");
```

The problem is that i have an error message that is telling me "cannot resolve method 'KeyBy(anonymous org.apache.flink.api.java.functions....'

[image]

Any help would be really welcome as Im struggling to understand what I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your `new MapFunction()...` is converting the incoming `String` to a `Tuple2<String, String>`, as otherwise having a `KeySelector<Tuple2<String, String>, String>` would make no sense.

If so, then you need to assign the result of `kafkaData.map(new MapFunction<...` to a DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> blah, and then have use that with your `keyBy`.

Though having said that, I don't see how you have a `keyBy().window()` of a `Tuple2<String, String>` resulting in a `DataStream<String> largeDelta`. So feels like multiple issues.

As an aside, for simple key selectors, instead of defining an anonymous function, use a lambda expression. E.g. `kafkaData.keyBy(r -> r.f1)` would do it.

Comment: As you correctly pointed out there are missing parts. I tried to simplify my question using a Tuple2 instead the tuple19 that I'm currently using. I will edit the question to clarify what is the issue.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using a `Tuple19`, as it makes the code very hard to understand (and implement corrected - e.g. what exactly is `.f17` in your Tuple?). Just define a POJO with appropriate getters/setters.

Comment: And my original answer explains the problem you're having. When you call `kafkaData.map(new MapFunction<...`, that returns a NEW stream, of type `DataStream<Tuple19<...>>`, but you're not capturing that result in a local variable that you would then use for your `.keyBy()`.

Comment: Thanks! The POJO make a lot of sense and also the explanation is logical, I got that from a theorical point of view. What I have tried to do is exacly what you suggested but in the last couple of days i didn't manage to do it properly. How can i .map get data back to flink for the windowing and use that .map for the keys. Would be possible for you to give me an example where you are capturing inside a local varialbe the .map and you are using for both windowing and .keyBy? I assume that once i got that I can use the same variable for all the analysis, so it would be extremly helpful.